# I can't make a message box, there is an error?

Tags: c#

I am trying to add on to my car rental program. Sorry for all the questions. I am still learning :). So I want my form to display an error message that pops up when you don't enter a number or if the text box is blank. I have tried:

```
 //If nothing is inserted in text, error box.
        int value = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtBegin.Text) || !int.TryParse(txtBegin.Text, out value)) // Test for null or empty string or string is not a number
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You entered: {0}!", value));
```

It is giving me an error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you building this in .NET 4.5?

Comment: I fixed it retyping it. I feel dumb. Anyway this is Windows App Form. But the code I entered is just simply popping a message box up with what the number the user put. I am trying to make it if there is nothing in inputted in text box, it will give an message box error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() requires targeting .NET 4.0 or higher.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Target framework setting.  VS2010 or higher required.

Watch the spelling, let IntelliSense help you fall in the pit of success.

You don't need it at all in this case.  The Text property of a TextBox can never be null and TryParse() will already return false if the string is empty.  Fix:

```
    int value = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtBegin.Text, out value))
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!");
    else MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You entered: {0}!", value));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is `IsNullorWhiteSpace`

If you care about backward compatibility use the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method.

Comment: Are you using `IntelliSense`?

Comment: No, [it is not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: And if you want the "ultimate backward compatibility", use `if (txtBegin.Text != null && txtBegin.Text.Trim() != "")`